# AnyLogic Fluid dynamically assign storage tank (visual representation)

Tags: fluid, dynamically-generated, anylogic

I have a custom **FuelTank** object, anylogic tank but with some extra logic.  It has a parameter **SimTank** of type "storageTank".  The anylogic "tank" block (inside the **FuelTank** object) has its "StorageTank" set to this parameter.

I now have a **TankFarm** object which in turn incorporates a number of these **FuelTank** objects.  And a Collection - *FuelTanks* to reference each of the tanks.  It has a parameter **SimTanks**, which is a one-dimensional array of type Other, storageTank[].

So now. 
If I configure the **TankFarm** object, select each tank in the object and one by one set each tank's **SimTank** parameter to "SimTanks[0]", "SimTanks[1]", etc.  then populate **SimTanks** with the list of storageTanks I want to use in my visual representation, everything works fine.  EXCEPT if I have less "storageTanks" in my **SimTanks** array than there are tanks in my **TankFarm** object.  (*which is understandable.  If I only have 4 storageTanks, but 5 tanks in my tankfarm, then tank 5 will have its "SimTank" parameter set to "SimTanks[4]" which of course does not exist in the "SimTanks" array* and correspondingly gives an error)

To get around this problem, I use a function and run it when the simulation starts:

```
for (int s=0; s<=(TankFarm.SimTanks.length-1); s++) 
  TankFarm.FuelTanks.get(s).SimTank = SimTanks[s];
```

So now if the user only added 4 "storageTank objects" to his visual simulation, only the first four tanks in the "TankFarm" are assigned a storageTank the last one is "null".

Code works (does not give an error), but when you run the model there is ZERO simulation, none, nothing happens with the StorageTank objects in the visual representation, they don't show anything; it is as if the AnyLogic tanks (inside the individual **FuelTank** objects), are not linked with the StorageTanks?

How do I fix this please"?  How do I dynamically assign the StorageTank objects dropped on the main window and added to the **SimTanks** array to the tanks in my **FuelTank** object?

(*To clarify, if I do it manually, one by one, it works - but then if I have less storageTanks than Tanks in my farm it gives an error.  If I do exactly the same dynamically, through code, it does not give an error, but the simulation does not work, the storageTanks does not show anything??*)

Comment: The following also DOES NOT work:

Comment: Drop a StorageTank on the main agent, name it storageTank1.  Drop a button.  Code the button: `TankFarm.FuelTanks.get(0).tank.storageTank = storageTank1`  - in other words I drill down to the FuelTank agent, then to the basic AnyLogiv block "tank" inside the agent and directly assign it an instance of 'storageTank'.

Comment: can you upload your model somewhere?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This issue has been resolved thank you.  I created a function inside the library object that returns a `StorageTank`.  Then added a parameter that the user configures to use the object's animation or add "his own" animation.  Each tank object in the library then calls the function which returns a StorageTank object - either the built-in object (built into the library object) or the one the user added manually.  The method works perfectly - user may drop the library object (which includes its own animation) but then configure it to not use that animation, in which case user has to build and assign his own animation.